# Why is react-router appending a trailing slash in the address bar to the location?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Super basic setup of

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path='/' />
  <Route path='/some-route' />
</BrowserRouter>
```

on load of a page, or refresh (note that `Link`s with a path of `/somewhere-else` will work as expected), `react-router` is appending a trailing slash in the address bar. Example: going to `http://localhost:8080/some-route` will get changed to `http://localhost:8080/some-route/`.

this will not happen if i set the `basename` on `BrowserRouter` to `/literally-anything`, however, i dont want to do this.

any ideas?

Comment: May this help.  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/820

Comment: yea i've seen that thread. it doesn't explain why it's happening though (when it previously wasn't)